# Чтение почты через imap на Python

Tags: python, imap, smtplib

Я пишу программу для чтения почты. И столкнулся с проблемой того,что когда я захожу через imap на почту
то мне нужно сначала зайти на почту и там уже разрешить доступ к почте с неизвестных источников / небезопасных программ. Только после этого я могу зайти на почту через программу. Как я могу обойти эту систему?

Comment: Да, но когда у тебя много почт...

Comment: Разобраться со STARTTLS.